# Symfony2 FormType to JSON

Tags: php, json, symfony

Is it possible somehow to serialize Symfony2 FormType into JSON? I have the following Type for User form.

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', 'text', array('label' => 'Name'))
            ->add('surname', 'text', array('label' => 'Surname'))
            ->add('username', 'text', array('label' => 'Username'))
            ->add('email', 'text', array('label' => 'Email'))
            ->add('isAdmin', 'checkbox', array('label' => 'Admin'));
    }
    ...
}
```

Possible to get the following or similar JSON format using Symfony2 itself, or I will need my custom parser?

```
{
    "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "label": "Name"
    },
    "surname": { 
        "type": "text",
        "label": "Surname"
    },
    "username": {
        "type": "text",
        "label": "Username"
    },
    "email": {
        "type":"text",
        "label":"Email"
    },
    "isAdmin": {
        "type": "checkbox",
        "label" : "Admin"
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may be looking for something like the [Liform bundle](https://github.com/Limenius/LiformBundle) which allows you to generate a JSON Schema from a Symfony form.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a form theme that would output your widgets any way you want to. Here's a [link to Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#form-theming) that explains how to create and apply form themes.

However, if you're implementing an API (otherwise why would you need to get the form as JSON?), you should definitely take a look at [FOSRestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle), as it implements form handling and serialization.